# postgres: apply aggregate function to column with spaces in name

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run a query like this

```sql
SELECT group, sum("a column with spaces") FROM x GROUP BY group
```

Unfortunately, I get the error `function sum(text) does not exist`. It appears to be interpreting my quoted identifier `"a column with spaces"` as a text string instead of column name. How can I specify that this is an identifier?

Comment: The error message indicates that despite the code in your question you are using single quotes around the name, e.g. `sum('a column with spaces')` (not double quotes as in your question)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to trick it into parsing it as an identifier -- prefix it with the table identifier or alias:

```sql
SELECT group, sum(t."a column with spaces") FROM table_name t GROUP BY group;
```

Answer (score 0):

Double-quotes are actually the right way to identify columns, but in this case it won't work.
I managed to apply an aggregate function renaming the column and removing its white spaces.

```sql
CREATE TABLE example (
    "column with space" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO example VALUES (1), (2);

SELECT SUM(column_with_space) 
FROM (
    SELECT "column with space" AS column_with_space
    FROM example
) AS example_query;
```

Got result:

| sum |
| --- |
| 3 |